# React 16 - unable to make a modal render using createPortal

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to render a loading notification modal while a POST is processing.
It seems like it should be very simple using createPortal but the modal never displays.

I added a div in index with an id of modal:

```
<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="modal"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the react component.  When the test button is clicked the state of showModal is set to true:

```
import React, { Component, Header } from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Row, Col, Button } from 'reactstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import ProcessingModal from '../Modals/ProcessingModal';

export class TestModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            showModal: false,
        }
        this.handleShowModal = this.handleShowModal.bind(this);
    }

    handleShowModal() {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    }


render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='container-fluid'>
                    <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center', border: 'none' }}>
                        Header Text
                    </h2>
                    <br />                    
                    {this.state.showModal ? <ProcessingModal /> : null }
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={6}>
                            <Button onClick={this.handleShowModal} type="button">test</Button>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </div>
         );
     }
```

This is the ProcessingModal js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

const ModalContent = (
    <div className='modal text-center'>
        <div className="spinner-border text-success"><br />
            Loading...
        </div>
    </div>
);

function ProcessingModal(props) {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(ModalContent, document.querySelector("#modal"));
}

export default ProcessingModal;
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think first argument of createPortal expect a React Element, not React Component.

In `ProcessingModal.js`, wrap `ModalContent` into JSX Element:

```js
   return ReactDOM.createPortal(<ModalContent/>, document.querySelector("#modal"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Styling was my issue.  The modal style had display: none;
Once that was removed it worked.